# Correct way to position in bootstrap container

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, css-position

I'm creating a website which will contain one page with absolute positioned divs. Technologies I use is CSS layout, Bootstrap framework, angular 2.

Problem that I'm now facing is that I need to place some divs absolutely. They are placed within the container. Structure looks like this:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="myowncontainer">
        ... some stuff at the beginning ...

        <div class="absolutecontainer col1 row1">
            ... content ...
        </div>

        ... more of the absolute containers ...
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.myowncontainer
{
    width: 2600;
    height: 700;
}

.absolutecontainer
{
    position: absolute;
}

.col1
{
    left: 5px;
}

.row1
{
    top: 5px;
}
... and other rows and columns ...
```

Before you ask why I'm not using bootstrap features to build a table, the col1 and row1 can't be displayed as table. If you are familiar with sports, I need to show the double KO system, each of absolutely positioned divs is one match. It will not form a table by any means.

So, what makes it hard: when I place the divs absolutely, they will overflow out of the container div. I would like to position them WITHIN the container. I have tried also some relative positioning, but failed. There was always something that made it very hard or imposible to position the divs correctly.

Actual problems:

- in chrome the myowncontainer is not of the specified width and height, the absolutely positioned divs are touching the edges of page even though the myowncontainer is bigger to provide some space around it. other browsers work fine (firefox, edge).
- absolute positioning has the 0,0 point in the upper left corner of the PAGE, not the parent DIV. So the absolute divs are overflowing the container to the top and left. Maybe the relative positioning should be used, but how do I specify relative to WHAT? I mean, angular 2 places some tags around a code snippet when this snippet is also a component. I don't want to place it relatively to this generated tag.
- what's the worst, in android's chrome the content is not shown at all. The absolute divs are completely missing. I haven't checked other browsers, makes no sense to me when the most commonly used browser is not working at all.

Of course I know the responsivness of such page will be bad, but that's what users have to accept, this is not a common page, it is a big overview that HAS to be placed exactly as I want it. It is also the only page in whole system that won't be responsive. So if you know how exactly should I place the divs, don't care about the responsivness... or if there is any way? I don't think so :) I believe everything can be solved by one simple trick, probably the relative positioning... but how? Site is online (still not used) and I can send URL privately if needed.

Thanks to everybody in advance.